# How to find wires of a given width in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad

I have almost finished a somewhat dense layout, and I have found out on the statistics menu that there are two wires of a smaller width that I don't really want to be using any more. The thing is that I am unable to spot these wires by just looking at the layout.

Is there a way to search for and highlight wires of a given width in Eagle?

Comment: Change the DRC rule to larger than the width you want to remove and do a DRC check.

Comment: @WesleyLee Surely that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @RogerRowland -- done! I was in a rush so decided to just comment instead of posting a single sentence as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

1 - Type "DRC" in the command line.

2 - In the "Sizes" tab, change the "Minimum Width" size to larger than the width of the traces you want to change.

[image]

3 - Do a DRC check. On the "DRC Errors" window it will show you "width" errors and the layer they are in. If you check the "centered" box, it will center the trace on the editor window when you select a specific error instance.

[image]
[image]

This does not answer your broader question of "how to highlight specific trace widths" but solves your problem of finding traces narrower than 'x' mil/mm.

Comment: Yeah! This is definitely useful for this specific case. I hope there's something less hacky for the more general case though.